# Error in upgrading code from v5 to v6 in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The error is the home page search bar isnt funtioning in v6 in react-router-dom , it isnt visible anymore in header of home page. Thereby i cant seem to understand the best way to render the search bar into header and make it work. Thank you for everyone in advance.

Header.js

```
import React, { Fragment  } from 'react'
import Search from './Search'
import {Route, useNavigate,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

const Header = () => {

  return (
    <Fragment>
         <nav className="navbar row">
      <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
        <div className="navbar-brand">
          <img src="./imgs/logos.png" style={{width:'80px',height:'70px'}}/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0">
       <Routes> // **place where the search bar should render** 
       <Route path='/search/:keyword' render={({ navigate }) => <Search navigate={navigate} />} />
       </Routes>
     
      </div>

      <div className="col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 mt-md-0 text-center">
        <button className="btn" id="login_btn">Login</button>

        <span id="cart" className="ml-3">Cart</span>
        <span className="ml-1" id="cart_count">2</span>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

export default Header

**Search.js**

```
import  React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Link , useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Search = () => {

    const [keyword,setKeyword] = useState('');
  
    let navigate=useNavigate();
    
    const searchHandler= (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        if(keyword){
            navigate(`/search/${keyword}`)
        }else{
            navigate("")
        }




    }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
         <div className="input-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="search_field"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Product Name ..."
            onChange={(e)=> setKeyword(e.target.value) }
          />
          <div className="input-group-append">
            <button id="search_btn" class="btn">
              <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default Search
```

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

import './App.css';
import Header from './components/layouts/Header';
import Footer from './components/layouts/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home';
import ProductDetails from './components/products/ProductDetails';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
     <Header/>
     <div className="container container-fluid">
       <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails/>}  />
            <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={Home} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
     <Footer/>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you haven't nested the `routes tag` in `router tag` in your `Header` function.

Replace your `Header function` with below code:

```
const Header = () => {

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
         <nav className="navbar row">
      <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
        <div className="navbar-brand">
          <img src="./imgs/logos.png" style={{width:'80px',height:'70px'}}/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0">
       <Routes> // **place where the search bar should render** 
       <Route path='/search/:keyword' render={({ navigate }) => <Search navigate={navigate} />} />
       </Routes>
     
      </div>

      <div className="col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 mt-md-0 text-center">
        <button className="btn" id="login_btn">Login</button>

        <span id="cart" className="ml-3">Cart</span>
        <span className="ml-1" id="cart_count">2</span>
      </div>
    </nav>
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is what I get when I run the above code:"Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app."@dharmikPatel

Answer (score 1):

`react-router-dom@6` `Route` components have no `render` prop. They have only an `element` prop to render routed components on ***as JSX***. To render `Search` when the home page comes out, where the header is part of the home page, render it on the same paths as `Home`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Search />} />
  <Route path='/search/:keyword' element={<Search />} />
</Routes>
```

Home

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="container container-fluid">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />}  />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Shows error in console that says: "No routes matched location "/" "

Comment: @Bryan This is because the `Header` component isn't rendering a route for `"/"`. When do you *actually* want the `Search` component to be rendered?

Comment: I want it to be rendered when the home page comes out, where the header is part of the home page.

Comment: @Bryan Ok, I see. You will need to add a `"/"` route then that also renders the `Search` component like you did with `Home` in the `App` component. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines in file Header.js

```
<Routes> // **place where the search bar should render** 
   <Route path='/search/:keyword' render={({ navigate }) => <Search navigate={navigate} />} />
</Routes>
```

And replace by this

```
<Search />
```

You can watch this video for more understand about navigate
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjHT_NKR_gU&t=991s at 15:53